# Searching number without reminder

Tags: c

What does the main problem in my algorithm,I need to find the smallest positive number which divided from 1 to 20 with out divider...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
int num,j=2;
int saveNum=20;
bool flag = false;
while(!flag)
{
    num = saveNum;
    while(num%j==0 && j<=20)
    {
        num /= j;
        j++;
    }
    if(j>20)
        flag = true;
    else
    {
     saveNum++;
     j=1;
    }
}
printf("Done");
printf("%d",saveNum);
}
```

Comment: Your algorithm doesn't make any sense. Try one which does.

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to solve.  Are you trying to get the solution to `2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10*11*12*13*14*15*16*17*18*19*20`?  You will overflow 32 bits before you get there.

Comment: @TheCrackNuts Because with one which does, you'll have greater chances of getting a meaningful result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you missing a `printf` to see what your intermediate results are?  That might help you get an idea as to what is going on internally.

But I don't really understand what you're trying to solve.  Do you want the result: `2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10*11*12*13*14*15*16*17*18*19*20`?

Because I think that's what you are currently computing.  However, you'll overflow before you get there and iterating to that point will take you a while.

If instead you're trying to find the smallest number that is divisible by every number less than or equal to 20, then you may want to revisit your update of `num /= j`.